# Css display: contents; causes underline stop working

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list with a few list elements inside of it. in each list element, we have ankers.

**Expected result**
On hover to the Anker, the expected behavior is to add underline to the Anker

**Actual result**
On hover to the Anker, the underline is not being added to the Anker.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>bla bla bla <a>underline text </a> bla bla bla</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
grid-gap: 14px;
gap: 14px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 1.61; }

a {
color: #00829a;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 500;
display: contents; }

a:hover {
text-decoration: underline; }
```

Does anyone know why it happens and how to fix it? I have tried to add display: revert; to the a: hover but it breaks all CSS.

Comment: Stop using flexbox for text content: https://dev.to/afif/never-make-your-text-container-a-flexbox-container-m9p . That's you real issue

Comment: Why would you set `display: contents` on those links here in the first place, I can't see any sense in that.

Comment: @CBroe because he's using display:flex on li (which is wrong) so he is trying to fix a wrong thing with another wrong thing

Comment: @TemaniAfif ah, yes, in that context it kinda makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-4/#line-decoration :

> Note: Line decorations are propagated through the box tree, not through inheritance, and thus have no effect on descendants when specified on an element with [display: contents](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#propdef-display).

Answer (score -1):

You can just remove the **display: content** property. And it should work. Like this :

**CSS**

```
ul li {
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-start;
            grid-gap: 14px;
            gap: 14px;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 1.61;
        }

        a {
            color: #00829a;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: 500;
            display: contents;
        }

        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is change css display value to inline-block.

```css
ul li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  grid-gap: 14px;
  gap: 14px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.61; }
  
  a {
  color: #00829a;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
}
  
  a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>bla bla bla <a href="#">underline text </a> bla bla bla</li>
    </ul>
```